# RegEx to replace a string inside a string in Visual Studio 2015 search

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I've got the following string all over my code:

```
languageService.getString("string_from_key");
```

Now I want to replace `"string_from_key"` (with the quotation marks) with `KeyClass.string_from_key`.

I am struggling with the RegEx in Visual Studio 2015 to search and replace the mentioned strings all over the code. `string_from_key` is a changing value, thats why RegEx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Maybe you missed a tiny detail?

Comment: So you want `languageService.getString("string_from_key");` to become `languageService.getString(KeyClass.string_from_key);`, and then `languageService.getString("banana");` to become `languageService.getString(KeyClass.banana);`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try matching more, and then using replacement parameters:

Search:

```
languageService.getString\("(\w+)"\);
```

Replace:

```
languageService.getString\(KeyClass.$1\);
```

Double quotes are not metachars in regexes, but parentheses are. `\w+` will match more or more "word" characters, but that includes underscores (because history) so is very useful for identifiers.